# How to use the Adobe Acrobat JavaScript SDK to save the pdf from the browser?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

Adobe Acrobat allows us to insert JS in the pdf:

```
if (app.alert("Do you want to save the pdf?", 2, 3) === 4) {
    // Save the pdf.
}
```

I tried: `app.save()`, `app.execCommand("Save")`, but both failed.

Is it possible that using the Adobe Acrobat JavaScript SDK to trigger the save action inside of the browser?

Comment: In acroJS are no methods like app.save() or app.execCommand("Save"). In the Adobe Acrobat JavaScript API Reference you will find only doc.SaveAs or app.execMenuItem("SaveAs") with explanations and examples. Regards, Reinhard

Comment: @ReFran Yes, I saw these, but they didn't work in the browser...